# Should I use JSON econding, JavaScript encoding or both?

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, xss

I’ve  started to work with security of a website and my task is to prevent XSS attack. I’ve seen the OWASP rules to deal with it. However, I am not sure about which of these rules I should use on my specific case. 
I have the following .jsp file:

```
<%
    // Get Requests
    InputData data = new InputData(request);
    int idBcomp = data.getInt("bcomp");

    Bcomp bcomp = new Bcomp();
    BcompDao bcompDao = new BcompDaoImpl();

    bcomp.setId(idBcomp);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {

        for (Bcomp s : bcompDao.find(bcomp)) {
            json.accumulate("id", s.getId());
            json.accumulate("nome", s.getNome());
            json.accumulate("nox", s.getNox());
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        json.accumulate("erro", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        json.accumulate("erro", e.getMessage());
    }

    out.write(json.toString());
%>
```

I also have the .js file that receives and manipulates the JSON created by the file above. In this file I have the following code:

```
function import(idBcomp) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/bcomp.jsp',
        data: {bcomp: idBcomp}
    }).done(function (r) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(r);

        $("#nome").val(obj.nome);
        $("#nox").val(obj.nox);
        $("#id_bcomp").val(obj.id);

    });
}
```

Therefore, my question is: Should I use javascript encode, JSON encode or both? And where should I do the encoding?
I am using [OWASP XSS API](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233.1_-_HTML_escape_JSON_values_in_an_HTML_context_and_read_the_data_with_JSON.parse) for encodeForJavaScript and JSON encoding

Comment: you realize that json **IS** javascript? (J)ava(S)cript (O)bject (N)otation. It's just a slightly more strict notation, but valid json **IS** valid javascript.

Comment: All JSON is JavaScript, but not all JavaScript is JSON.  `application/json` indicates data only, where `application/javascript` could be executed.  In a security context, it's not good practice to identify data as an executable source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON encoding.  JSON indicates to the browser that the content is DATA ONLY and should not be executed.  JavaScript encoding indicates a potentially executable bundle.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. However, I still have a question. In this code, the data that is used to create the JSON is an untrusted data. Should I encode these data ? If yes, which encoding should I use ? Or do I just need to add the `application/json` header? In which specific part of the code is it vulnerable ?

Comment: Just regular old JSON encoding. Your decoder should not try to execute the data as it is transformed into JavaScript values.  If it does, your decoder is woefully broken.  Then it is only vulnerable once the data are added to the DOM, and you should most definitely take precaution to scrub the data, but that is between you and how you use the data.  You should not be relying on the encoding to manage that.